# How to deploy Umbraco local site to server?

Tags: sql-server, umbraco7

I don't know how can I deploy my local Umbraco 7.2 local website to a normal server (Windows 2012 VPS). I know I need to copy all files to the server, but I can't figure out how can I copy the database. I download an SQL Management Studio 2012, but I don't know the access details, because when I installed the site to my localhost, the installer didn't ask me. Maybe on thing, as I remember, the DB type. It was SQL CE.

Does anybody know how can I access to the local and server database? Whats is Umbraco database name?
Is there any else configuration?

Maybe an easier option to deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- Open the database \App_Data\Umbraco.sdf see [How do you open an SDF file (SQL Server Compact Edition)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953248/how-do-you-open-an-sdf-file-sql-server-compact-edition) (it is not in new SQL Management Studio versions) and do your database things to deploy.
- Copy the SQL CE default \App_Data\Umbraco.sdf
- Create a package
- Using tools like Courier

And see the web.config for your connectionString:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="umbracoDbDSN" />
    <add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Umbraco.sdf;Flush Interval=1;" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    <!-- Important: If you're upgrading Umbraco, do not clear the connection string / provider name during your web.config merge. -->
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed the Umbraco.sdf file as well. I didn't tested yet, because I would like to move from local DB to SQL Express.