# Syncing a SQL Server CE database with a regular SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, umbraco, data-synchronization

There's an Umbraco site that various people been contributing content to. It runs on a hosted domain using a SQL Server Compact edition database for the CMS. It's about to go live and I need to sync the dev database to the live SQL Server instance which is hosted by a third party.

I just ass(u)me(d) that I could attach the `.sdf` to my local SQL Server and use a commercial tool (Redgate/SQLDelta etc.) to copy it to the live db. This does not seem to be possible. While [I have managed to attach the `.sdf` using Linqpad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1953248/2671514), I can't connect to it like a regular database.

The best option seems to be to script out the entire database, but this seems like an impossible task using just Linqpad (no flies on Linqpad, obviously - it isn't the tool for such a task). Any less onerous options would be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use my free "SQL Server Compact Toolbox" Visual Studio extension for this. It can generate a script of the entire SQL Server Compact database, that you can then run against an empty SQL Server database.

Answer (score -1):

In the past I did this kind of scenario wherein I need to copy the data from the SQL Server CE to a SQL Server database. Have you tried adding the `.sdf` to an ODBC then linked that ODBC to SQL Server?

Comment: There is no ODBC provider for SQL Server Compact