# SQL Server: Merge statement compilation error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-merge

I have used SQL Server `MERGE` statement in my stored procedure and when compiling the stored procedure I'm getting this error:

> The object reference [dbo].[Student].[ID] differs only by case from
>   the object definition [dbo].[Student].[Id].

My table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] 
(
    [Id]        INT          NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [LastName]  VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [StateID]   INT          NULL,
    [CityID]    INT          NULL,
    [IsActive]  BIT          NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].USP_UpdateStudent
AS
    Declare @Data xml  

    SET @Data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
                 <Students>  
                    <Student>    
                       <ID>2</ID>    
                       <FirstName>Tridip</FirstName>    
                       <LastName>Bhattacharjee</LastName>    
                       <IsActive>true</IsActive>    
                       <StateID>2</StateID>    
                       <CityID>4</CityID>  
                    </Student>
                 </Students>'  
    BEGIN TRY
        MERGE INTO Student as Trg  
        USING (SELECT
                   d.x.value('id[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') as ID,
                   d.x.value('FirstName[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') as FirstName ,  
                   d.x.value('LastName[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') as LastName,
                   d.x.value('StateID[1]','int') as StateID,
                   d.x.value('CityID[1]','int') as CityID,
                   d.x.value('IsActive[1]','bit') as IsActive
               FROM
                   @data.nodes('/Students/Student') as  d(x)) AS Src ON Trg.ID = Src.ID  

        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE 
            SET Trg.FirstName = Src.FirstName,  
                Trg.LastName = Src.LastName,
                Trg.StateID = Src.StateID,
                Trg.CityID = Src.CityID,
                Trg.IsActive = Src.IsActive

        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
            INSERT (FirstName, LastName, StateID, CityID, IsActive) 
            VALUES(Src.FirstName, Src.LastName, Src.StateID, Src.CityID, Src.IsActive);   
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      -- Insert Error into table
      --INSERT INTO #error_log(message)
      --VALUES (ERROR_MESSAGE());
    END CATCH
```

What's my mistake causing this error? Thanks

### Edit

Got 2 good links to connect sql compact db by SSMS and LinqPad. here is the link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16692386/728750
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47534/how-do-i-view-a-microsoft-sql-server-compact-database

Thanks

Comment: So, what happens if you make the case of the column name consistent (i.e. use "Id" everywhere instead of mixing "Id" and "ID", like you are with `Trg.ID`, say?) (Also, is this an error or a warning? Presumably this is coming from your client tools rather than the server? Think there's probably [an option not to bother checking](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/32a856d6-e5f9-4536-89bf-2c2f1cb9032e/disabling-object-reference-differs-only-by-case-warnings-from-database-updates?forum=ssdt)...)

Comment: I believe that this is an SSDT *warning* (so, a tool you've not mentioned, and a warning, rather than an error), correct?

Comment: i am using Sql server compact db from VS2013 IDE and write store proc there.

Comment: thanks problem solve the moment i change the column name in student table fro id to ID. thanks

Comment: i am using VS2013 and open compact db from IDE. so tell me what option i should on/off to get rid of this case sensitive issue. share idea. thanks

Comment: can we open compact db from sql server management studio? any idea

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care about the case settings in the SQL, then you can disable this warning in the Project Settings by unchecking the "Validate casing on identifiers" box
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a SQL Server error as such, just a warning from your development tools. It's telling you that you're being inconsistent with the case of your object names, in this case mixing and matching `Id` and `ID` (note the lower case "d").

In most cases with SQL Server, it won't actually matter and your SQL will still run; in my experience most installations are case-insensitive. But being consistent is generally a good thing, and might prevent future problems, so I'd just fix your code so you consistently use the column name exactly as it's declared in your table definition.

Comment: i am using VS2013 and open compact db from IDE. so tell me what option i should on/off to get rid of this case sensitive issue. share idea. thanks

Comment: What exact tool is this error actually coming from? If it's SSDT, did you [check the article I provided in my comment](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/32a856d6-e5f9-4536-89bf-2c2f1cb9032e/disabling-object-reference-differs-only-by-case-warnings-from-database-updates?forum=ssdt) to see if that's applicable?

Comment: (Or possibly: Project properties->Build->Suppress Transact-SQL Warnings, and add 71558, assuming that's the warning number you're seeing. I'm really not sure, as I don't use Visual Studio for interacting with SQL Server.)

Comment: can we open compact db from sql server management studio? any idea